# jQuery Datatables server_side example not connected to front end

Tags: jquery, pagination, server-side, datatables

I have implimented the example: http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html
only to discover that this example gets all data up front. even if you are paginating. This means that the pagination doesn't actually send any data to the server...so basically...the server_side example is incomplete.

In other words, let's say I have 100 records with pagination enabled and I am using the server side example.
All 100 records load and the backend queries are essentially never called because the UI for the table never sends any query parameters.

I need to know what I'm missing to make this actually send the vars to the PHP. Perhaps somebody could show us a 'working' example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters the client send to the server are here http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side
And you can find some scripts to handle the data on the server with different technologies here http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/

Comment: I figured it out...I must have confused two tutorials because I was overriding fnServerData with an ajax callback...lol